# Azure log analytics

Tags: security, azure-log-analytics

I have to fetch the report containing the list of Azure VMs having security patches pending and name of those patches to be updated/installed using kusto query language in log analytics.Please help me out on this and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe below is the query in basic form which you are looking for.

```
Update
| where (Classification has "Security") and (UpdateState =~ "Needed") and (Approved != false)
| project Computer, Title
```

For more information and for source of the query, please refer [this](http://Hi%20Vamsi%20Krishna,%20I%20believe%20below%20is%20the%20query%20in%20basic%20form%20which%20you%20are%20looking%20for.%20%20Update%20%7C%20where%20(Classification%20has%20%22Security%22)%20and%20(UpdateState%20=~%20%22Needed%22)%20and%20(Approved%20!=%20false)%20%7C%20project%20Computer,%20Title%20%20For%20more%20information%20and%20source%20of%20the%20query,%20please%20refer%20this%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-tutorial-update-management%20Azure%20document.) Azure document.